# Shell Icon Overlay Identifiers missing although 15-slot limit hasn't been reached

Tags: windows, onedrive, shell-icons

I've recently noticed that my OneDrive for Business icons (sync/out of sync/currently syncing) are missing. I've researched the issue and found out that for a lot of users the issue can be fixed if they ensure that they stay below the 15-slot limit for these icons. However, I only have 5 slots taken. I've also followed advice to add a space before the reg-entry so it's bumped to the top of the list, again without success. Microsoft offers a little fixing-tool that I've run, but that also failed to bring the icons back. I am out of ideas at this point, and my IT department is not really of any help.

My laptop runs Windows 7, 64-bit, I am on Office 2013.

Any hints will be greatly appreciated. 
Aileen

Comment: Update: I just found out that when I am in a document (Word, Excel) and go to Save As and then browse for a location, the icons in that Windows explorer window show up. They are still not showing up when I just open Windows explorer.

Comment: This eventually fixed it for me: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nishants/2015/01/19/the-mysterious-issue-of-disappeared-green-ticks-in-onedrive-for-business/